# Como calcular a quantidade de conexões em uma Deep Network?

Tags: machine-learning, redes-neurais, deep-learning

Tenho exatamente esse cenário e preciso saber a quantidade de conexões que esse conjunto tem. Procurei em diversos lugares e não tenho certeza da resposta. Ou seja, não sei calcular o número de conexões da minha rede, isso ainda não está claro para mim. O que tenho é exatamente o seguinte:

**Tendo bias em tudo, menos no input
- Input: 784
- First hidden layer
  - Output: 400
- Second hidden layer
  - Output: 200
- Output layer
  - Output: 10

Eu calcularia isso da seguinte forma:
    ((784 * 400) + bias) + ((400 * 200) + bias) + ((200 * 10) + bias) = XXX

Não sei se isso está correto. Preciso de ajuda para entender como resolver isso, e se não for simplesmente algo matemático, qual a teoria para fazer esse calculo?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Se você escrever isso como multiplicação de matrizes - ao meu ver - fica mais fácil de calcular o número de parâmetros (ou se você quiser chamar de conexões) da sua rede.

Suponha que o seu input X seja uma matrix `X[n, 784]` em que `n` é o número de observações.

Uma rede com 2 camadas uma com 200 neurônios e uma com 10. Ficaria algo +- assim:

```
Y[n, 10] = ativacao(X[n,784]*P1[784, 200] + B1[200])*P2[200,10] + B2[10]
```

Em que `P1`, `P2`, `B1`, `B2` são matrizes de parâmetros.
Agora você consegue conferir se a sua conta está correta, basta contar o número de elementos das matrizes de parâmetros.

No caso: 784*200 + 200 + 200*10 + 10